# Theorem 1.13 of the book Brownian motion by Morters and Peres: Proof explanation

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, brownian-motion

This is theorem 1.13:

For every constant $c < \sqrt{2}$, almost surely, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $0 < h < \epsilon$ and $t \in [0,1-h]$ with

$$|B(t+h) - B(t)| \geq c \sqrt{h \log(1/h)} $$

Proof:

Let $c < \sqrt{2}$ and define, for integers $k,n \geq 0 $ the events
$$A_{k,n} =\bigg\{B((k+1)e^{-n})-B(ke^{-n}) > c c\sqrt{n}e^{-n/2} \bigg\}$$
then, using lemma 12.9, for any $k \geq 0$,
$$\mathbb{P}(A_{k,n}) = \mathbb{P}\{B(e^{-n}) > c\sqrt{n}e^{-n/2}\} = \mathbb{P} \{B(1) > c \sqrt{n} \} \geq \frac{c\sqrt{n}}{c^2n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-c^2n/2}$$

By our assumptions on $c$, we have $e^n \mathbb{P}(A_{k,n}) \to \infty$ as $n \uparrow \infty $. Therefore using $1-x \leq e^{-x}$ for all $x$
$$ \mathbb{P} \bigg( \bigcap_{k=0}^{\lfloor e^{n}-1 \rfloor} A_{k,n}^c\bigg) = (1-\mathbb{P}(A_{0,n}))^{\lfloor e^n \rfloor} \leq \exp(-e^n \mathbb{P}(A_0,n)) \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty$$

I understand everything until now, the only part I don't understand is the last one:

By considering $h = e^{-n}$ one can now see that, for any $\epsilon > 0$,
$$\mathbb{P} \bigg\{|B(t+h)-B(t)| \leq c \sqrt{h\log(1/h)} \forall h \in (0,\epsilon),t \in [0,1-h] \bigg\} = 0 $$
And that's all they wrote. I understand that this last equality implies the result, what I don't understand is how they got this result. First of all $h = e^{-n}$ so I guess it is an abuse of notation to use $h$ inside the event. Also, by replacing $h$ in the definition of $A_{k,n}$ one can get $|B(kh+h) - B(kh)| > c \sqrt{h\log(1/h)}$ but I don't see how this implies the last equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\{|B(t+h)-B(t)|\leq c\sqrt{h log(\frac{1}{h})} \ \forall h \in (0,\epsilon), t\in[0,1-h]\} \\
\subset
\{B(t+h)-B(t)\leq c\sqrt{h log(\frac{1}{h})} \ \forall h \in (0,\epsilon), t\in[0,1-h]\} \\
\subset \{B((k+1)2^{-n})-B(k2^{-n})\leq c\sqrt{n}e^{-\frac{n}{2}} \  \forall k=0,1,\dots ⌊^n−1⌋\}
$$
for any $n$ so that $e^{-n}<\epsilon$. But
$$
\{B((k+1)2^{-n})-B(k2^{-n})\leq c\sqrt{n}e^{-\frac{n}{2}} \  \forall k=0,1,\dots ⌊^n−1⌋\}=\bigcap_{k=0}^{⌊^n−1⌋}A_{k,n}^c
$$
so
$$
\mathbb{P}(\{|B(t+h)-B(t)|\leq c\sqrt{h log(\frac{1}{h})} \ \forall h \in (0,\epsilon), t\in[0,1-h]\}) \leq \mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{k=0}^{⌊^n−1⌋}A_{k,n}^c)
$$
for sufficiently large $n$. Taking $n \to \infty$ yields the result.